# Initialising Arrays and Objects: using brackets or 'new'?

Tags: javascript

When initialising Arrays and Objects in JavaScript, is there any difference between these two statements:

```
var a = [];
var a = new Array();
```

or between these two statements:

```
var b = {};
var b = new Object();
```

If there is a difference, which is to be preferred?

Comment: Please refer the link for the Array Initialization difference [http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) [http://javascript.infogami.com/Javascript_in_Ten_Minutes](http://javascript.infogami.com/Javascript_in_Ten_Minutes) Hope these links helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there aren't any significant differences. You could use both, but if you use javascript for web client side scripting, it's better to use the shorter syntax, because the shorter the javascript code, the faster it will get downloaded and executed.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets. Point.

They are shorter, they don't have hidden issues, and they are easier to pre-fill ( `var a = [1,2,3,{"use":"brackets"},"because they are cool!"];`  ).

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden issues"?