# Initialising Date variable-Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, initialization

This question might sound silly but it really bugs me and I could not find any relevant answers. Is there any way to initialise a javascript variable of date type other than using the `new Date()` ?. I have the doubt which is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596028/initialising-arrays-and-objects-using-brackets-or-new). I need to know if there are any shorter representations.

Comment: why  are you looking something for `other than using the new Date()` ?

Comment: @manikantgautam lets just say that I'm curious. Since we have [] for arrays and {} for objects, I'm curious to kow if there is anything available for date.

Comment: There is no Date literal.

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN Web Docs:

> JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no literal syntax.

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

So no, there is no other way. If you don't like it that way, you can take a look at date libraries like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)